# Нужно что бы после вывода = вы водился и ответ

Tags: c++, вывод

```
     #include <iostream>
     using namespace std;
     int main() {
     int a , sum = 1000;
     cin >> a;
     cout << "I am Ghoul" << endl;
     while (sum >= -7) {
     cout << sum << " - 7=" << endl;
     sum = sum - 7;
     }
     return 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

А чуть-чуть, ну самую чуточку - включить головной мозг?

```
cout << sum << " - 7 = ";
sum = sum - 7;
cout << sum << endl;
```